# Although I used 'drawnow' and 'hold on', last plot still appears in animation - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, video, matlab-figure

I read a lot of answers here, but for some reason my animation still doesn't work as expected.

The axis range should vary from frame to frame. The 'Hurricane Center' caption should remain in the center all the time, but the captions from the previous frames must be erased. Also, I'm afraid that some of the data from previous parts remain.

I used `hold on` and `draw now` but it still happens.

---

The animation can be seen here:

[image]

---

Code:

```
v = VideoWriter('test_video.avi');
v.FrameRate = 4;
v.open()   

hold on
for i=1:length(relevant(1,1,:))      
    if isempty(relevant) == 0     
        title('Lightning around Hurricane Jerry')
        grid on  

        ylim([Interp_Jerry(i,2)-Radius Interp_Jerry(i,2)+Radius])
        xlim([Interp_Jerry(i,3)-Radius Interp_Jerry(i,3)+Radius])

        ylabel('latitude')
        xlabel('longitude')

        text(Interp_Jerry(i,3),Interp_Jerry(i,2),txt1); 

        scatter(relevant(:,3,i),relevant(:,2,i),'.');
        drawnow
        pause(0.1);  

        v.writeVideo(getframe(fig));
    end
end  
v.close()
```

Comment: The text remains because you use `hold on`. Try adding `hold off` right before `text()` and `hold on` right after it.

Comment: Its not "although" its "because"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best of the two worlds:

```
v = VideoWriter('test_video.avi');
v.FrameRate = 4;
v.open()   

hold on;
for i=1:length(relevant(1,1,:))      
    if ~isempty(relevant)  % Corrected     

        if i == 1
            % Prepare first plot and save handles of graphical objects
            ht = text(Interp_Jerry(i,3),Interp_Jerry(i,2),txt1); 
            hold on;
            hs = scatter(relevant(:,3,i),relevant(:,2,i),'.');

            ylabel('latitude')
            xlabel('longitude')
            title('Lightning around Hurricane Jerry')
            grid on  
        else
            % Update graphical objects
            set(ht, 'position', [Interp_Jerry(i,3), Interp_Jerry(i,2)]);
            set(hs, 'XData', relevant(:,3,i) , 'YData' , relevant(:,2,i));
        end

        ylim([Interp_Jerry(i,2)-Radius Interp_Jerry(i,2)+Radius])
        xlim([Interp_Jerry(i,3)-Radius Interp_Jerry(i,3)+Radius])

        drawnow
        pause(0.1);  

        v.writeVideo(getframe(fig));
    end
end  
v.close()
```

Comment: I'm curious why you hold on before the loop *and* inside the `i==1` condition, when you then directly update the data anyway? Also the use of `~` is appropriate, but can you even see any point in the `if` check for whether `relevant` is empty, when we must have `length(relevant(1,1,:) >= 1` to even enter the loop? Good use of setting text position otherwise.

Comment: If you remove `hold on`, the scatter plot will erase the text. Matlab implies a `hold off` if you do not specify otherwise. The data from previous cycles will not remain because the code is updating the `XData` and `YData` properties of the scatter plot at each cycle, thus erasing the previous data. Concerning your last point, you are absolutely right. I did not notice that the cycle was based on `length(relevant(1,1,:))`, only the redundant `isempty(relevant) == 0`.

Comment: Ah okay, as I commented on my own answer we can fix that by putting the `text` command after the `scatter` command though, correct? Surely the text wont be removed if you're just changing the data of the scatter though, so no new plot => no need for a hold?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the previous data to remain, then you shouldn't use `hold on`... I think you should revise your code as follows:

```
v = VideoWriter('test_video.avi');
v.FrameRate = 4;
v.open();  
fg = figure();
% Do not hold on, so that data is not retained frame-to-frame
for i=1:length(relevant(1,1,:))     
    % You don't need to test if 'relevant' is empty, since you're looping to its length!
    % New plot
    scatter(relevant(:,3,i),relevant(:,2,i),'.');
    % Customise plot (labels / axes / text / ...)
    title('Lightning around Hurricane Jerry')
    ylabel('latitude')
    xlabel('longitude')
    ylim([Interp_Jerry(i,2)-Radius Interp_Jerry(i,2)+Radius]);
    xlim([Interp_Jerry(i,3)-Radius Interp_Jerry(i,3)+Radius]);   
    text(Interp_Jerry(i,3),Interp_Jerry(i,2),txt1);     
    grid on;      
    drawnow;
    % You don't need to pause whilst plotting, you already set the video framerate.
    % pause(0.1); 
    v.writeVideo(getframe(fg));
end  
v.close()
```

Comment: Shoutout to the void: I'm curious why my answer got a downvote when it fixes the issue the OP was facing. Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but I do not think your solution works: the `scatter()` will erase the `text()` without a `hold on` in the middle.

Comment: Ah I'd rather have heard that comment than a downvote, since it can be easily fixed by putting the `text` after the `scatter` as I've now edited :)

Comment: Yeah, I think it is StackOverflow policy to comment when you downvote.

Comment: [**It is encouraged**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes), especially if you have <2k rep, although not policy :) thanks for your insight though, your answer is better anyway

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing the text every time, just modify its position in the loop. Create a text object out side of the loop

```
t = text(position1, position2, txt);
```

in the loop change the position and if necessary the text

```
set(t, 'position', [new_position1, new_position2]);
```

Comment: Whilst correct, the asker also said they didn't want the data to remain, which it still will. And if you clear the data, are you not going to clear `t` (from the figure), making this redundant?